# Proofs of Theorems with naive Modal Logic to motivate their incorporation into formal Modal Logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I want to show why Modal Logic tries to incorporate the two following implications

$\square A \to \square \square A$

$\diamond A \to \square \diamond A$

as valid sentences by showing that a natural understanding of Necessity and Possibility leads to those two implications as valid and since Modal Logic wants to mimic our natural understanding of Necessity and Possibility as closely as possible it is bound to incorporate those two implications as valid sentences (theorems). So I wanna prove these implications with naive/informal Modal Logic. I wanna know if I succeed with my proofs.

Proof $\square A \to \square \square A$

Assume $\square A$. Now in addition we hypothetically assume $\neg \square \square A$, i.e. $\diamond \neg \square A$, i.e. one can think of at least one instance where $\neg \square A$ but since in that very instance our assumption $\square A$ holds as well we got a contradiction, and so we can infer $\square \square A$.

Proof $\diamond A \to \square \diamond A$

Assume $\diamond A$. Now in addition we hypothetically assume $\neg \square \diamond A$, i.e. $\diamond \neg\diamond A$, i.e. one can think of at least one instance where $\neg\diamond A$ but since in that very instance our assumption $\diamond A$ holds as well we got a contradiction, and so we can infer $\square \diamond A$.

Comment: What's a reference/source for "Modal Logic wants to mimic our natural understanding of Necessity and Possibility as closely as possible" and/or "[...] one reason to invent modal systems like S4, S5 etc. to make those two implications become valid was to mimic the natural and naive modal logic intuitions."?

Comment: @ac15 There was a lot of discussions of just this back in the early days. For example there's a famous 1959 paper by E. J. Lemmon "Is there only one correct system of modal logic?" which discusses the relation between different modal systems and different intuitive notions of necessity. And this follows on from debates that had been going on for more than a quarter of a century.

Answer (score 2):

These statements are not true in general for modal logics.

For $\square A \to \square\square A$, consider the following frame:

The worlds are $1, 2, 3$ and $R = \{(1, 2), (2, 3)\}$.

Suppose $A$ holds precisely at world $2$.

Then, starting from world $1$, $\square A$ hold but $\square\square A$ fails.

For $\lozenge A \to \square \lozenge A$, the example above works as well.

$\lozenge A$ holds of world 1, but $\square \lozenge A$ does not.

These two formulas are actually imposing conditions on the accessibility relation in our frame.

$\square A \to \square \square A$, if $A$ is allowed to range over arbitrary variables (or arbitrary formulas) and we start from any world in the frame, insists that the accessibility relation is **transitive**:

$$ aRb \land bRc \implies aRc \;\; \text{for all worlds $a,b,c$} $$

I think this is easier to see if we note that $\square A \to \square\square A$ expresses the same property as $\lozenge\lozenge A \to \lozenge A$.

$$ [\forall A](\square A \to \square\square A) \iff [\forall A](\square \lnot A \to \square\square \not A) \iff [\forall A](\lnot \lozenge A \to \lnot \lozenge \lozenge A) \iff [\forall A](\lozenge \lozenge A \to \lozenge A) $$

Intuitively, this says that any world we can reach in two jumps can be reached in one jump, which is transitivity.

Similarly, $\lozenge A \to \square\lozenge A$ expresses the idea that any reachable world is reachable remains reachable from all subsequent worlds.

$$ aRb \land aRc \to bRc $$

This is a [Euclidean relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_relation), which is kind of an obscure condition that I've only ever seen in modal logic.

---

Interestingly, a relation being transitive and Euclidean does not imply that it's an equivalence relation.

The empty relation on any set is trivially not an equivalence relation, but also ...

Consider the following relation on $\{1, 2\}$.

$$ \{ (1, 2), (2, 2) \} $$

And the following relation on $\{1, 2, 3\}$.

$$ \{ (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3), (3, 2) \} $$

Comment: You are right but my proof wants to show that these implications are right with naive modal logic, i.e. just with the notion of necessity A = ~A is logically false, possibility A = ~A is not logically true and the common equivalences but without all the technical/formal gobbledygook. Because as I understand it, one reason to invent modal systems like S4, S5 etc. to make those two implications become valid was to mimic the natural and naive modal logic intuitions. I want to show here with these proofs that those intuitions indeed have the implications valid.

Comment: I don't think naive modal logic is really precise enough to handle iterated modal operators, and any way of making it precise involves giving it a semantics. For example, what is the intended meaning of something being *possibly necessarily true*?

Comment: $\diamond \square A$ informally means: there is at least one case/chance where ~A is logically/always false. $\diamond A$ = ~A is not a tautology, $\square A$ = ~A is a contradiction. That is how we‘d understand the modalities in everyday life, expressed in logical terms.